# Excel find the maximum of visible cells

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010 if want to find the max of a row of data, but I want the formula to take the max of only the visible values. Is this possible in excel 2010 with a worksheet function?

Comment: You may need `AGGREGATE` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally like to ask if you mean row or column of data.

- A row of data in a single row?
  e.g. the data is in A1, B1, C1.
- Or a row of data - the data is one below the other in a single *row*? 
  e.g. A1, A2, A3 (i.e. in a single column).

Also, how are you hiding the values?  Is it through a filter, or right-clicking and selecting `hide`?

If it's the second option and you're filtering you can use  `=SUBTOTAL(104, $A$1:$A200)`.  This will return the maximum unfiltered value.
If you want to include manually hidden rows as well then use 4 rather than 104. `=SUBTOTAL(4, $A$1:$A200)`
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939

Unfortunately this doesn't work across columns.  `=SUBTOTAL(4, $A$1:$H$1)` will return the maximum value, but hiding columns won't change the result.

**Edit:**  You may be able to do something with `=Cell("width",A1)` to find hidden columns - it will return 0 if the column is hidden.

**Edit 2:** To use `Cell` add a *helper* row (I've used row 1).  In cell A1 type `=Cell("width",A1)` and drag across.
With the figures you're getting the maximum value for in row 2 you can now use the array formula `{=MAX(IF($A$1:$M$1>0,$A$2:$M$2))}` (use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to finish the formula which puts the curly {} brackets around the formula).

**NB:** Manually hiding a column won't force a recalculation, so you'll have to press F9 for the formula to update.

Comment: The data is in a row: A1,B1,C1,... I'll try with Cell("width,A1)

Comment: I've added the formula needed for columns.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help! I hope many people upvote your answer